# How do i fix "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, typeerror

I'm tring to create a python app for a school project, when i finished programming this error popped out and i dont know how to fix it.

The application is for Windows and not for linux.
I alredy saw other posts on this error, but no one helped me.

```py
1 import os
2 from sys import *
3 from msvcrt import *
4 from webbrowser import *
5
6 def main():
7   while True:
8       os.sys('cls')
9       Manifesto()
10      print("[...]\n> ")
11      article = input("")
12      if article == 1:
[...]                   [...]
240 def wait():
241    msvcrt.getch()
242
243 if __name__ == '__main__':
244 main()
245
```

this is the first part and last part of my code, my code isn't structured on multiple files, only this.

in the console the output is

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\Python>python costituzione.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "costituzione.py", line 244, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "costituzione.py", line 10, in main
    while True:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

C:\Users\John\Documents\Python>
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: `os.sys('cls')` what is this line supposed to be doing? Are you trying to run a command?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the error because `os.sys` is a module and not a callable object (a function).  Essentially, what you are doing is equivalent to

```
import A
A()
```

You can consider using `os.system` instead, which executes a given command in a subshell.  Your `main` function would then be,

```py
def main():
    while True:
        os.system('cls')
        Manifesto()
        print("[...]\n> ")
        ...
```

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. Can you elaborate on how os.system solves this problem?

Comment: `os.system` is used to execute a command. Edited the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`os.sys` refers to the `sys` module imported into the `os` module, not the `os.system` function that you are looking for. Do instead:

```
os.system('cls')
```